# Why does ArcGIS ModelBuilder tool Iterate less than expected Number of Times?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have an ArcGIS ModelBuilder tool (with an iterator in the workflow) and the tool iterates through approximately 30 features then stops.  I have checked that:

1. It is not instructed to iterate only a certain number of times; and
2. That the input feature class does not have a selection on it.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

Additional details :

The iterator churns through a dataset and creates a new FC by unique ID.  The next steps are complex and include building terrains.  The behavior is usually corrected when I shut down ArcMap and open up a new MXD.

Comment: I've seen it, but only when the actions performed during each iteration are long and complex.  I've assumed that some system resource has been exhausted.  Can you edit your question to provide more details about what operations are performed during each iteration, please?  Can you test what happens if "much less" is done during each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently revisited this tool that was giving me problems.  I finally found out what the issue was.  The tool was writing hundreds of feature classes to a feature dataset.  Once that number got to be above a couple hundred, the performance slowed and the tool would only iterate 27 times.  If I switch the writing of the feature classes to a different FGDB or FD, the performance comes back to normal and it iterates much more than 27 times.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen, but only when the actions performed during each iteration are long and complex. I've assumed that some system resource has been exhausted.

To try and get a handle on what is happening you could:

1. Watch the process in the Windows Task Manager to see if its memory usage is very high before it stops; and
2. Test what happens if "much less" work is done during each iteration.

Comment: I've monitored system performance in the task manager and memory usage does not spike before it stops.  I recently upped my virtual memory and am running the tool now and it is iterating through features and not stopping after 30 times.